# Usb-to-serial terminal cannot find usb device in /dev

Tags: command-line, usb

I want to use Hirsute Hippo Ubuntu and the gtkterm serial terminal but there is not any usb device in /dev directory.

I used it a few years ago.

At that time I had to **insmod cdc-acm.ko** from command line to get device in /dev directory. Now  I cannot get it.

I did as follows:

```
steve@Apa:~$ sudo insmod cdc-acm.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not load module cdc-acm.ko: No such file or directory
```

I tried to change directory where I found it before:

```
steve@Apa:~$ cd /usr/lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/class
steve@Apa:/usr/lib/modules/5.11.0-37-generic/kernel/drivers/usb/class$ sudo insmod cdc-acm.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module cdc-acm.ko: File exists
```

What shall I do to get any usb device?

Comment: Please share output of `lsusb -t` with USB serial converted connected. Why do you think that you need CDC ACM?

Comment: See if it's provided by a package you need to install: `dpkg -S cdc-acm.ko`.

Comment: @Norbert I used cdc-acm earlier when I needed usb terminal for my microcontroller development. At this moment I have /dev/ttyASM - but my Ubuntu behaves annoying. It is random event if a cold boot results /dev/ttyASM  or not.

Comment: @waltinator I installed and hope the miracle of random exist/not exist /dev/ttyASM will be fixed.